# Just can't get the image slider go horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just an nooby with JS, I did a lot of research for letting the image-slider slide horizontal. But it never worked. Here's an link to the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e13wuo6d/12/) .

This is the JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider li').hide().filter(':first').show();
    setInterval(slideshow, 3000);
});


function slideshow() {
    $('#slider li:first').slideToggle('slow').next().slideToggle('slow').end().appendTo('#slider');
}
```

Comment: `slideToggle` animates the height. It's designed for opening and closing paragraphs or drop-down menus. It's not an image slider. `http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/` Consider using something like `fotorama.js` plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blocknotes/e13wuo6d/13/

```
$('#slider li:first').animate({width: 'toggle'}).next().animate({width: 'toggle'}).end().appendTo('#slider');
```

Comment: Thank you but do you know the code that the second image folows the first image like this [example](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.slider)

Answer (score 0):

you make effect like this with using .toggle('slide') instead of slideToggle()

```
function slideshow() {
    $('#slider li:first').toggle('slide').next().toggle('slide').end().appendTo('#slider');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/e13wuo6d/14/)

Comment: I've tried it with SlideToggle() but it had the same effect, so I tried that one, as I said, I'm just an nooby to JS :)